# ggplot stat_smooth: change look of multiple bands

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'm trying to customize the look of multiple loess plots within the same graph for different levels of a group var. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828498/ggplot2-multiple-stat-smooth-change-color-linetype) post, but wasn't able to make it work:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, color=Species, linetype=Species)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "loess")
```

[image]

I'd like to change the color of each band and line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the looks with for example the `scale_color_manual` scale. In the example below I also used `override.aes` within `guides` to get a nice legend as well:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, color=Species, linetype=Species)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(fill=Species), method = "loess", size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green","blue","red")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green","blue","red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed","dotted","solid")) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill="white",size=1.2)))
```

this gives:

[image]

Other alternatives to the manual scales are the `hue` and `brewer` scales.

Comment: You answer is very complete, as usual, allowing customization. I posted mine and deleted it later thinking that the line type was the same but I realised that there's no need to add manually color, fill or line type, just those two lines.

Answer (score 2):

I added `size = 2` so you can see that the line type is different for each line:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, color=Species, linetype=Species)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "loess", aes(fill = Species), size= 2)
```

[image]